# Merging spatial data with non-spatial data brings up NA values for Non-Spatial Data

Tags: r, csv, merge, spatial, na

I'm working with U.S Census Data (containing attributes and spatial data/geometry as well) that I'm trying to merge with my own database that I created in excel (police stop rates and counts within census tracts) and converted to a CSV file. Both databases share a unique column identifier "GEOID" and the same number of observations, but when I use merge(), left_join(), or even inner_join() I continuously get all of my data from my spatial file back but the variables from my other datable all come back as NA. What should I do? Thanks for the help!

What I'm working with:

```
    library(readr)

SDPD_Data_Census <- read_csv("SDPD_Data_Census.csv", 
     col_types = cols(GEOID = col_character(), 
         policestop = col_integer(), policestoprate = col_number(), 
         totp = col_skip()))

View(SDPD_Data_Census)

#I convert my census data into a shape file
SD.city.tracts <- st_read("SD.city.tracts.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#My SPD_Variable_List is missing geometry data that would allow me to plot the policerate variable onto a map. To fix this, I merged my census data (that has geometry values) and my police data together

#I merge my police data with my census data using GEOID as the common factor
SD_Police_Census <- left_join(SD.city.tracts, SDPD_Data_Census)

#I use names() to check if the datasets were merged, here it shows that the policestoprate and policestop columns are now included with the census data but are showing NA values
head(SD_Police_Census, n=5) 
Joining, by = "GEOID"Simple feature collection with 5 features and 34 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -117.1949 ymin: 32.73966 xmax: -117.1554 ymax: 32.75932
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs
        GEOID tpop tpopr medincome     pfpov   powner  phsgrad    pbach      pdiv    psingm pnhwhite nhwhite    pnhasn nhasn    pnhblk nhblk     phisp
1 06073000100 3250  3250    138864 0.0000000 36.83077 1.969231 40.86154  7.323077 0.2153846 76.67692    2492  4.369231   142 0.0000000     0 15.876923
2 06073000201 1915  1915     90673 0.9921671 24.90862 3.342037 41.35770 12.584856 2.2454308 84.38642    1616  2.140992    41 0.5221932    10  7.049608
3 06073000202 4583  4583     66438 0.6764128 18.93956 4.494872 43.42134 12.000873 2.4874536 71.61248    3282  9.382501   430 0.8727907    40 13.855553
4 06073000300 5094  5094     69028 0.9422850 13.42756 3.945819 45.75972 13.172360 2.0416176 72.49706    3693  2.179034   111 5.1040440   260 16.195524
5 06073000400 3758  3758     75559 0.0000000 11.09633 5.268760 40.89941 11.362427 3.1665780 61.76158    2321 11.043108   415 5.0026610   188 19.425226
  hisp pnonwhite nonwhite    pfborn nfborn     poth oth nhwhitec nonwhitec nhasnc nhblkc  othc  hispc  tpoprc       ent policestoprate policestop
1  516  23.32308      758 13.384615    435 3.076923 100   646438    853300 248715  89133 67268 448184 1499738 0.7397115             NA         NA
2  135  15.61358      299  6.370757    122 5.900783 113   646438    853300 248715  89133 67268 448184 1499738 0.6069625             NA         NA
3  635  28.38752     1301 15.775693    723 4.276675 196   646438    853300 248715  89133 67268 448184 1499738 0.9111694             NA         NA
4  825  27.50294     1401  9.187279    468 4.024342 205   646438    853300 248715  89133 67268 448184 1499738 0.8925200             NA         NA
5  730  38.23842     1437 18.121341    681 2.767429 104   646438    853300 248715  89133 67268 448184 1499738 1.1083576             NA         NA
                        geometry
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1922 3...
2 MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1789 3...
3 MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1785 3...
4 MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1686 3...
5 MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1709 3...

#When I try to map the policestoprate variable it shows that all policestoprate data is missing
```

Hopefully, someone can help me out, I really need this to work since it for a thesis and I'd be sad to abandon this project cause of 2 variables...

EDIT:
when I use `head(SDPD_Data_Census)` it shows:

```
 GEOID      policestoprate policestop
    <chr>       <dbl>       <int>
    6073000100  0.0000000   0       
    6073000201  1.5665796   3       
    6073000202  0.6545931   3       
    6073000300  3.1409501   16      
    6073000400  26.3437999  99      
    6073000500  1.5285845   5
```

So the data is there and has no NA values when left in its original form, but when merged with my census data only the two columns from my police data shows NA values throughout. Using `full_join()` produced the same results as well.

EDIT 2:
I looked over my police database and it turns out all of my GEOID values are missing a 0 in the beginning which is why they couldn't match with the GEOID values from the census database (which has these zeroes). Very silly mistake but now I have to manually insert 0s into all of my GEOID values on excel and hopefully they merge this time. (when I did a `full_join()` on the two datasets it turns out that the police data was preserved but they were added at the very bottom of the newly made dataset because they couldn't match with the census GEOID values).

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a reproducible example that includes small sample datasets, but if that is too tricky, could you show use what the `head()` of `SDPD_Data_Census` looks like? And do you get any data in the two problematic columns if you do a `full_join()` instead of a `left_join()`? To me, it looks like dplyr does not manage to find matching values in GEOID...

Comment: Hi! When I use {head()} on my police database it shows that all the correct data is there and has no NA values. When I use {full_join()} it still shows the same output in my original post example :(

Comment: I left an edit with what it looks like when I use both of your ideas if that helps clarify things more! Thanks again for taking the time to help me I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 3: I manually fixed my police database and added 0s in front of my GEOIDs to match with the one from the census database. Using `full_join()` after that worked perfectly and now I can map my police stop rates with no issues! Lesson learned: try not to work at 2am on coding because you can make silly mistakes like this.

Comment: Excellent! You should also be able to use your original `left_join()` if you want to use your spatial table as the main dataset (and discard anything from the other that doesn't match on GEOID).
I think you should be able to tick your own answer as correct too, if you want to mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I think your suggestion is great, I am working with too many databases now and I definitely should consider reducing it through that.